# forming a 2D array in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a 2D array consisting of the URL and text in an "a href" element.

I think I got it working, but I am not sure if this is the correct structure for a 2D array.  From the output in the console, it looks like a 1D array.

I need it to be like this `[link URL, linkText]`

example:   `[http://www.yahoo.com, Yahoo!]`

Could someone please take a look and see if this is actually a 2D array?

Thanks

Here is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kxkHZ/13/

```
var linkArray = [];
$('[class=hrefURL]').each(function (i) {
    var text = ($(this).text());
    var url = ($(this).attr('href'));
    linkArray.push(url, text);
});

for (var i = 0; i < linkArray.length; i++) {
   console.log(linkArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Use .trim() to format your url/text before inserting them into the array =]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
linkArray.push(url, text);
```

to

```
linkArray.push([url, text]);
```

or use objects instead of arrays as the inner element for something a bit more structured:

```
linkArray.push({url: url, text: text});
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'use objects instead of arrays'...could you please elaborate?  Thanks

Comment: Oh ok, so both url and text are objects with a property(url,text)?

Comment: Not quite; each array element is a single object with two properties, `url` and `text`. You could just _try_ it and see, of course `:)`

Answer (score 3):

Every item you push its at the same level. Try this:

```
var linkArray = [];
$('[class=hrefURL]').each(function (i) {
    var text = ($(this).text());
    var url = ($(this).attr('href'));
    linkArray.push([url, text]);
});

for (var i = 0; i < linkArray.length; i++) {
   console.log(linkArray[i]);
}
```